# Vue Native: 'Invariant Violation'

Tags: react-navigation, expo, vue-native

I'm trying to get up and rolling with Vue Native, and I'm running into the same error whenever I attempt to navigate beyond the initial screen

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.

```
 Check the render method of ReactVueComponent.
 in ReactVueComponent (at SceneView.js:17)
 in SceneView (at CardStack.js:466)
 in RCTView (at View.js:60)
 in View (at createAnimatedComponent.js:154)
 in AnimatedComponent (at Card.js:12)
```

When searching my dir for `ReactVueComponent`, it doesn't exist, nor does `SceneView.js`, nor does `RCTCView`, etc. My guess is that's because they are generated with the code compiles?

My router, `index.vue` is set up as follows

```
<template>
    <root>
      <app-navigation></app-navigation>
    </root>
</template>


<script>
import React from "react";
import { StackNavigator, navigationService } from "vue-native-router";
import { Root } from "native-base";
import WelcomeScreen from "./screen/WelcomeScreen.vue";
import HomeScreen from "./screen/home.vue";

const AppNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    Welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Welcome",
    headerMode: "none"
  }
);
export default {
  components: { Root, AppNavigation }
};
</script>
```

My `WelcomeScreen` component(this loads correctly. The button, on push, throws the error)

```
<template>
      <nb-content padder>
        <nb-form>
          <view :style="{marginTop:300}">
            <nb-button block :on-press="login">
              <nb-text>Login</nb-text>
            </nb-button>
          </view>
      </nb-content>
</template>

<script>
import { Dimensions, Platform, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import { NavigationActions } from "vue-native-router";

export default {
  props: {
    navigation: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  methods: {
    login() {
      this.navigation.navigate("Home");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

The `HomeScreen` component, which fails to render:

```
<template>
    <nb-container :style="{flex:1, backgroundColor: '#fff'}">
        <nb-header>  
            <nb-body>
                <nb-title>title</nb-title>
            </nb-body> 
        </nb-header>
        <nb-content>
            <nb-list>
                <li>thing 1</li>
                <li>thing 2</li>
                <li>thing 3</li>
            </nb-list>
        </nb-content>
    </nb-container>
</template>

<script>
import React from "react";
import { Dimensions } from "react-native";

const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;

export default {
  props: {
    navigation: Object
  }
};
</script>
```

Any tips on this would be much appreciated. Not much out there on Vue Native yet, and I've tried to follow the few examples I've seen to the best of my ability. Double and triple-checked my dependencies and they all seem to be in place.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using `<li>` tags which are not supported. If you check native base docs. The correct tag to be used within `nb-list` is `nb-list-item`. http://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#list-def-headref